# DetachedCriteria with 3 OR conditions

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How can I achieve this query using DetachedCriteria:

```
Select * from 
    MyTable
Where 
    (conditionA = true) or 
    (conditionB = true) or 
    (conditionC = true) or 
    (conditionD = true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Disjunction class like so:

```
DetachedCriteria.For<MyTable>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Disjunction()
             .Add(Restrictions.Eq("conditionA", true))
             .Add(Restrictions.Eq("conditionB", true))
             .Add(Restrictions.Eq("conditionC", true))
             .Add(Restrictions.Eq("conditionD", true)));
```

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
DetachedCriteria.For<MyTable>()
        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("conditionA", true) ||
             Restrictions.Eq("conditionB", true) ||
             Restrictions.Eq("conditionC", true) ||
             Restrictions.Eq("conditionD", true));
```